# Why isn't the correct application name showing up on the browse app screen?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, background, textview

I am working with Android Studio 1.0. Here's my manifest file

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application> 
And inside strings.xml
<string name="app_name">Demo app</string>
```

The attribute I want to focus on is android:label
From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html, I read that android:label for the application is "A user-readable label for the application as a whole". Now from that I am assuming, that this is the name that the user should see when he or she browses for the app. However when I installed the application on my emulated GenyMotion 4.4.4 Nexus device, here is what I saw 
[image]

Why is the label showing MainActivity and not the app label/name I specified? From what I read, this should be the right attribute to use to set label name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the intent-filter that describes which activities have a launcher icon in the application tray, and so it is the label that you specify on the activity that determines how it appears there. The label for the application names the package as a whole, not specific entry points that get a launcher icon.

Comment: Where can you see the label for the application name?

Comment: @committedandroider any place that refers to your package as a whole, for example the listing on the Play Store.

Comment: So to clarify on google play, you see the name demo app but when you install, you see the label for the application launcher, MainActivity on the app browse screen?

Comment: Correct. If your app only has one activity that has an entry in the application list, you probably want to use the same label both for the package and for that activity (so as to avoid confusing users), but this separation is useful when a single package has multiple entry points.